# Fullcalendar wordpress submit booking

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

i need creat this [calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACGYi.png) i use fullcalendar jquery but i have many problem for integrate on my php page. I need save data for update woo commerce booking or save with submit listing job (wp jobmanager).
Thank you for your help

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 
  /* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {
    //console.log($(this));
        // events drags
        var eventObject = {
   title: $.trim($(this).text()),
            className: $(this).attr('className'),
            color: $(this).attr('color'),
            type: $(this).attr('type'),
            textColor: $(this).attr('textColor'),
        };
        
        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);
        $.fullCalendar.formatDate(eventObject.start,'yyyy-MM-dd');
        
        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });
        
    });
 // inti calendar   
 
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prev,next',
        },
        height: 350,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        //contentHeight: 600,
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,

        events: $('#calendar').attr('values'),

        // on dropping
        drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped
        
            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
            
            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            
            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date,'yyyy-MM-dd');
            copiedEventObject.end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date,'yyyy-MM-dd');
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            
            // render the event on the calendar
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);  

            // Get currents dates
            var startCurrent = new Date(copiedEventObject.start);
            if (copiedEventObject.end == null) {
                var endCurrent = startCurrent;
            } else {
                var endCurrent = new Date(copiedEventObject.end);
            }

            // Get events dates
            var pulledEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
            // Compare to events dates
            var nbEventCheck = pulledEvents.length-1;
            for (var i = 0; i < nbEventCheck; i++) {
                var startPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].start);
                var endPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].end);
                if (endPulled.getTime() == 0) {
                    endPulled = startPulled;
                }
                // containing
                if (startCurrent >= startPulled && endCurrent <= endPulled) {
                    // begin
                    if (startCurrent.getTime() == startPulled.getTime()) {
                        // start pulledEvent later
                        pulledEvents[i].start = new Date(endCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                        // if same remove
                        if (endCurrent.getTime() == endPulled.getTime()) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',pulledEvents[i]._id);
                        }
                    }
                    // finish
                    else if (endCurrent.getTime() == endPulled.getTime()) {
                        // finish pulledEvent earlier
                        pulledEvents[i].end = new Date(startCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * -1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                    }
                    // contain
                    else {
                        // copy pulledEvent to the end
                        var copiedpulledEvent = $.extend({}, pulledEvents[i]);
                        copiedpulledEvent._id = "copy"+Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);;
                        copiedpulledEvent.source = null;
                        copiedpulledEvent.start = new Date(endCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1));
                        copiedpulledEvent.end = pulledEvents[i].end;
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedpulledEvent, true);
                        // cut beginning pulledEvent
                        pulledEvents[i].end = new Date(startCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * -1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', pulledEvents[i]);
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', pulledEvents[i], true);
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // on dropping from calendar
        eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {

            // Get currents dates
            var startCurrent = new Date(event.start);
            if (event.end == null) {
                var endCurrent = startCurrent;
            } else {
                var endCurrent = new Date(event.end);
            }
            
            // Get events dates
            var pulledEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
            // Compare to events dates
            var nbEventCheck = pulledEvents.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < nbEventCheck; i++) {
                // avoid to compare to the same copy element
                if (event._id == pulledEvents[i]._id) {
                    i++;
                    if (i >= nbEventCheck) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                var startPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].start);
                var endPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].end);
                if (endPulled.getTime() == 0) {
                    endPulled = startPulled;
                }

                // containing
                if (startCurrent >= startPulled && endCurrent <= endPulled) {
                    // begin
                    if (startCurrent.getTime() == startPulled.getTime()) {
                        // start pulledEvent later
                        pulledEvents[i].start = new Date(endCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                        // if same remove
                        if (endCurrent.getTime() == endPulled.getTime()) {
                           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',pulledEvents[i]._id)
                        }
                    }
                    // finish
                    else if (endCurrent.getTime() == endPulled.getTime()) {
                        // finish pulledEvent earlier
                        pulledEvents[i].end = new Date(startCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * -1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                    }
                    // contain
                    else {
                        // copy pulledEvent to the end
                        var copiedpulledEvent = $.extend({}, pulledEvents[i]);
                        copiedpulledEvent._id = "copy"+Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);
                        copiedpulledEvent.source = null;
                        copiedpulledEvent.start = new Date(endCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1));
                        copiedpulledEvent.end = pulledEvents[i].end;
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedpulledEvent, true);
                        // cut beginning pulledEvent
                        pulledEvents[i].end = new Date(startCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * -1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', pulledEvents[i]);
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', pulledEvents[i], true);
                    }
                    // update pulledEvent
                    var startPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].start);
                    var endPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].end);
                }

                // externing
                if (startCurrent <= endPulled && endCurrent >= startPulled) {
                     // left
                    if (endCurrent <= endPulled) {
                        pulledEvents[i].start = new Date(endCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                        // if same remove
                        if (endCurrent.getTime() == endPulled.getTime()) {
                           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',pulledEvents[i]._id)
                        }

                    }
                    // right
                    else if (startCurrent >= startPulled) {
                        pulledEvents[i].end = new Date(startCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * -1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                        if (startCurrent.getTime() == startPulled.getTime()) {
                           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',pulledEvents[i]._id)
                        }
                    }
                    // surround
                    else
                    {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',pulledEvents[i]._id);
                    }
                }
               
            }

        },

        // on event resizing
        eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {

            // Get currents dates
            var startCurrent = new Date(event.start);
            if (event.end == null) {
                var endCurrent = startCurrent;
            } else {
                var endCurrent = new Date(event.end);
            }

            // Get events dates
            var pulledEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
            // Compare to events dates
            var nbEventCheck = pulledEvents.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < nbEventCheck; i++) {
                // avoid to compare to the same copy element
                if (event._id == pulledEvents[i]._id) {
                    i++;
                    if (i >= nbEventCheck) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                var startPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].start);
                var endPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].end);
                if (endPulled.getTime() == 0) {
                    endPulled = startPulled;
                }

                // externing
                if (startCurrent <= endPulled && endCurrent >= startPulled) {
                     // left
                    if (endCurrent < endPulled) {
                        pulledEvents[i].start = new Date(endCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                    }
                    // right
                    else if (startCurrent > startPulled) {
                        pulledEvents[i].end = new Date(startCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * -1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                    }
                    // surround
                    else
                    {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',pulledEvents[i]._id);
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // on click on event
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            if (confirm('Remove this event ?')) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',calEvent._id);
            }
        }
   // get localized date format using Moment.js
   // var lang = jQuery('html').attr('lang') || 'en';
 //   var locale = moment().locale(lang);
    var dateFormat = "d-m-y";

    // get origin date format from query string
    var originFormat = dateFormat;
   // if (originFormat) {
    //    originFormat = convertPHPFormatMoment(originFormat);
 // }


    // reformat date for current locale if different of origin format
    if (originFormat && originFormat != dateFormat) {
        var startField = $("#datepicker-start"),
            endField = $("#datepicker-end"),
            startDate = moment(startField.val(), originFormat),
            endDate = moment(endField.val(), originFormat);
        startField.val( startDate.format(dateFormat) );
        endField.val( endDate.format(dateFormat) );
    }

    // add hidden date_format field
    $("#datepicker-start").closest('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="date_format" id="date_format" value="'+ dateFormat +'">');

    $("#datepicker-start").datepicker({
            dateFormat: dateFormat,
            minDate: 0,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#datepicker-end").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                $("#datepicker-end").focus();
            }
        });

        $("#datepicker-end").datepicker({
            dateFormat: dateFormat,
            minDate: 0,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#datepicker-start").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });


 
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent, true);

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', newEvent.start);

        var color = $("#default-events label.active input").attr("color");
        $('td.fc-day').css('background-color', color);

        // empty date
        $('#datepicker-start').val('');
        $('#datepicker-end').val('');

        // reset bounds dates
        $('#datepicker-start').datepicker("option", "maxDate", null);
        $('#datepicker-end').datepicker("option", "minDate", null);
 
   
});
```

```html
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/fullcalendar/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/fullcalendar/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/fullcalendar/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/fullcalendar/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-gtg.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/fullcalendar/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js"></script>



<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="calendar_home" style="display:initial;">
                                                                                        
                            <div id="progress">
                                <div class="bar bar-photo-edit" style="display:none;">
                                    <span>Chargement en cours…</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="alert-box">
                                <div id="calendar-not-uptodate" class="alert alert-warning alert-calendar" style="display: initial;">
                                   Vous n'avez aucune période selectionné  
                                </div>
                                <div style="display: none;" class="alert alert-success alert-calendar" id="calendar-updated">
                                    Votre calendrier a été mis à jour
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <!-- date picker -->
                            <div id="datepicker-event" class="form-inline">

                                <label class="home_type">Créer une nouvelle période de disponibilité</label>

                                <div>
                                    <div class="form-group calendar-edition">
         


                                    <input id="datepicker-start" class="form-control " type="text"  placeholder="Du" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group calendar-edition">
                                    <input id="datepicker-end" class="form-control " type="text"  placeholder="jusqu'au" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select class="form-control">
                                            <option value="0" disabled="" selected="">Type de disponibilité</option>
                                            <option title="Disponible" classname="event-available" color="#d4f2e6" value="5">Disponible</option>
                                            <option title="Flexible" classname="event-ask-me" color="#CDE5f9" value="3">Flexible me contacter</option>
                                            <option title="Indisponible" classname="external-events event-unavailable" color="#E7E7E7" value="1">Indisponible</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <input class="btn btn-default calendar-edition" type="button" id="add_date"  value="submit">
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!-- #datepicker-event -->
                            <div id="datepicker-event"></div>
                            <!-- popup period delete -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="deletePeriod" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                            </button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Etes-vous sûr?</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <p>Etes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette période ?</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-basic" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="delete_period">Supprimer</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- calendar -->
                            <div id="calendar" class="fc fc-ltr" value="">
       </div>
                            <!-- default value -->
                            <div id="default-events">
                                <label class="">Disponibilité par défaut <span class="grey-color small italic text-default-value">Choisissez l'option qui décrit le mieux la disponibilité de votre maison durant l'année</span></label>

                                <label class="radio default-available active">
                                    <input type="radio" color="#d4f2e6" name="default-date" id="default-date-4" value="4">
                                    <span class="color-available small">Disponible</span>
                                    Ma maison est  généralement disponible 
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio default-ask-me">
                                    <input type="radio" color="#CDE5f9" name="default-date" id="default-date-2" value="2" >
                                    <span class="color-ask-me small">Demandez moi</span>
                                    Mes dates sont flexibles
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio default-unavailable">
                                    <input type="radio" color="#E7E7E7" name="default-date" id="default-date-0" value="0">
                                    <span class="color-unavailable small">Indisponible</span>
                                    Ma maison est habituellement indisponible
                                </label>
                                <label class="default-guestwanted">
                                    <span class="color-wanted small">test</span>
                                    Je recherche activement des Invités <br>
                                    <small><em>(période non disponible par défaut)</em></small>
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <div id="return-message"></div>

                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Next update but don't work. I need save availability of fullcalendar custom in wp job manager user as a field and update to availabity woo commerce booking calendar product. If anyone has a good idea on how to do this better,

```js
$(function() {
 
  /* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {
    //console.log($(this));
        // events drags
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()),
            className: $(this).attr('className'),
            color: $(this).attr('color'),
            type: $(this).attr('type'),
            textColor: $(this).attr('textColor'),
        };
        
        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);
        $.fullCalendar.formatDate(eventObject.start,'yyyy-MM-dd');
        
        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });
        
    });
 // inti calendar   
 
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prev,next',
        },
        height: 350,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        //contentHeight: 600,
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,

        events: $('#calendar').attr('values'),

        // on dropping
        drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped
        
            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
            
            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            
            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date,'yyyy-MM-dd');
            copiedEventObject.end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date,'yyyy-MM-dd');
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            
            // render the event on the calendar
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);  

            // Get currents dates
            var startCurrent = new Date(copiedEventObject.start);
            if (copiedEventObject.end == null) {
                var endCurrent = startCurrent;
            } else {
                var endCurrent = new Date(copiedEventObject.end);
            }

            // Get events dates
            var pulledEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
            // Compare to events dates
            var nbEventCheck = pulledEvents.length-1;
            for (var i = 0; i < nbEventCheck; i++) {
                var startPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].start);
                var endPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].end);
                if (endPulled.getTime() == 0) {
                    endPulled = startPulled;
                }
                // containing
                if (startCurrent >= startPulled && endCurrent <= endPulled) {
                    // begin
                    if (startCurrent.getTime() == startPulled.getTime()) {
                        // start pulledEvent later
                        pulledEvents[i].start = new Date(endCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                        // if same remove
                        if (endCurrent.getTime() == endPulled.getTime()) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',pulledEvents[i]._id);
                        }
                    }
                    // finish
                    else if (endCurrent.getTime() == endPulled.getTime()) {
                        // finish pulledEvent earlier
                        pulledEvents[i].end = new Date(startCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * -1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                    }
                    // contain
                    else {
                        // copy pulledEvent to the end
                        var copiedpulledEvent = $.extend({}, pulledEvents[i]);
                        copiedpulledEvent._id = "copy"+Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);;
                        copiedpulledEvent.source = null;
                        copiedpulledEvent.start = new Date(endCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1));
                        copiedpulledEvent.end = pulledEvents[i].end;
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedpulledEvent, true);
                        // cut beginning pulledEvent
                        pulledEvents[i].end = new Date(startCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * -1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', pulledEvents[i]);
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', pulledEvents[i], true);
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // on dropping from calendar
        eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {

            // Get currents dates
            var startCurrent = new Date(event.start);
            if (event.end == null) {
                var endCurrent = startCurrent;
            } else {
                var endCurrent = new Date(event.end);
            }
            
            // Get events dates
            var pulledEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
            // Compare to events dates
            var nbEventCheck = pulledEvents.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < nbEventCheck; i++) {
                // avoid to compare to the same copy element
                if (event._id == pulledEvents[i]._id) {
                    i++;
                    if (i >= nbEventCheck) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                var startPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].start);
                var endPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].end);
                if (endPulled.getTime() == 0) {
                    endPulled = startPulled;
                }

                // containing
                if (startCurrent >= startPulled && endCurrent <= endPulled) {
                    // begin
                    if (startCurrent.getTime() == startPulled.getTime()) {
                        // start pulledEvent later
                        pulledEvents[i].start = new Date(endCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                        // if same remove
                        if (endCurrent.getTime() == endPulled.getTime()) {
                           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',pulledEvents[i]._id)
                        }
                    }
                    // finish
                    else if (endCurrent.getTime() == endPulled.getTime()) {
                        // finish pulledEvent earlier
                        pulledEvents[i].end = new Date(startCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * -1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                    }
                    // contain
                    else {
                        // copy pulledEvent to the end
                        var copiedpulledEvent = $.extend({}, pulledEvents[i]);
                        copiedpulledEvent._id = "copy"+Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);
                        copiedpulledEvent.source = null;
                        copiedpulledEvent.start = new Date(endCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1));
                        copiedpulledEvent.end = pulledEvents[i].end;
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedpulledEvent, true);
                        // cut beginning pulledEvent
                        pulledEvents[i].end = new Date(startCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * -1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', pulledEvents[i]);
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', pulledEvents[i], true);
                    }
                    // update pulledEvent
                    var startPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].start);
                    var endPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].end);
                }

                // externing
                if (startCurrent <= endPulled && endCurrent >= startPulled) {
                     // left
                    if (endCurrent <= endPulled) {
                        pulledEvents[i].start = new Date(endCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                        // if same remove
                        if (endCurrent.getTime() == endPulled.getTime()) {
                           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',pulledEvents[i]._id)
                        }

                    }
                    // right
                    else if (startCurrent >= startPulled) {
                        pulledEvents[i].end = new Date(startCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * -1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                        if (startCurrent.getTime() == startPulled.getTime()) {
                           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',pulledEvents[i]._id)
                        }
                    }
                    // surround
                    else
                    {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',pulledEvents[i]._id);
                    }
                }
               
            }

        },

        // on event resizing
        eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {

            // Get currents dates
            var startCurrent = new Date(event.start);
            if (event.end == null) {
                var endCurrent = startCurrent;
            } else {
                var endCurrent = new Date(event.end);
            }

            // Get events dates
            var pulledEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
            // Compare to events dates
            var nbEventCheck = pulledEvents.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < nbEventCheck; i++) {
                // avoid to compare to the same copy element
                if (event._id == pulledEvents[i]._id) {
                    i++;
                    if (i >= nbEventCheck) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                var startPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].start);
                var endPulled = new Date(pulledEvents[i].end);
                if (endPulled.getTime() == 0) {
                    endPulled = startPulled;
                }

                // externing
                if (startCurrent <= endPulled && endCurrent >= startPulled) {
                     // left
                    if (endCurrent < endPulled) {
                        pulledEvents[i].start = new Date(endCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                    }
                    // right
                    else if (startCurrent > startPulled) {
                        pulledEvents[i].end = new Date(startCurrent.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * -1));
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', pulledEvents[i]);
                    }
                    // surround
                    else
                    {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',pulledEvents[i]._id);
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // on click on event
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            if (confirm('Remove this event ?')) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',calEvent._id);
            }
        }
 });
   // get localized date format using Moment.js
   // var lang = jQuery('html').attr('lang') || 'en';
 //   var locale = moment().locale(lang);
    var dateFormat = "d-m-y";

    // get origin date format from query string
    var originFormat = dateFormat;
   // if (originFormat) {
    //    originFormat = convertPHPFormatMoment(originFormat);
 // }


    // reformat date for current locale if different of origin format
    if (originFormat && originFormat != dateFormat) {
        var startField = $("#datepicker-start"),
            endField = $("#datepicker-end"),
            startDate = moment(startField.val(), originFormat),
            endDate = moment(endField.val(), originFormat);
        startField.val( startDate.format(dateFormat) );
        endField.val( endDate.format(dateFormat) );
    }

    // add hidden date_format field
    $("#datepicker-start").closest('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="date_format" id="date_format" value="'+ dateFormat +'">');

    $("#datepicker-start").datepicker({
            dateFormat: dateFormat,
            minDate: 0,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#datepicker-end").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                $("#datepicker-end").focus();
            }
        });

        $("#datepicker-end").datepicker({
            dateFormat: dateFormat,
            minDate: 0,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#datepicker-start").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });


 
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent, true);

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', newEvent.start);

        var color = $("#default-events label.active input").attr("color");
        $('td.fc-day').css('background-color', color);

        // empty date
        $('#datepicker-start').val('');
        $('#datepicker-end').val('');

        // reset bounds dates
        $('#datepicker-start').datepicker("option", "maxDate", null);
        $('#datepicker-end').datepicker("option", "minDate", null);
 
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://free-communiity.com/wp-content/themes/listable-172/listable/fullcalendar/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js"></script>
<link href="https://free-communiity.com/wp-content/themes/listable-172/listable/fullcalendar/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://free-communiity.com/wp-content/themes/listable-172/listable/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://free-communiity.com/wp-content/themes/listable-172/listable/fullcalendar/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://free-communiity.com/wp-content/themes/listable-172/listable/fullcalendar/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://free-communiity.com/wp-content/themes/listable-172/listable/fullcalendar/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://free-communiity.com/wp-content/themes/listable-172/listable/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-gtg.js"></script>
<script src="https://free-communiity.com/wp-content/themes/listable-172/listable/fullcalendar/datepicker-custom.js"></script>
<script src="https://free-communiity.com/wp-content/themes/listable-172/listable/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>




<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="calendar_home" style="display:initial;">
                                                                                        
                            <div id="progress">
                                <div class="bar bar-photo-edit" style="display:none;">
                                    <span>Chargement en cours…</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="alert-box">
                                <div id="calendar-not-uptodate" class="alert alert-warning alert-calendar" style="display: initial;">
                                   Vous n'avez aucune période selectionné  
                                </div>
                                <div style="display: none;" class="alert alert-success alert-calendar" id="calendar-updated">
                                    Votre calendrier a été mis à jour
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <!-- date picker -->
                            <div id="datepicker-event" class="form-inline">

                                <label class="home_type">Créer une nouvelle période de disponibilité</label>

                                <div>
                                    <div class="form-group calendar-edition">


                                    <input id="datepicker-start" class="form-control " type="text"  placeholder="Du" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group calendar-edition">
                                    <input id="datepicker-end" class="form-control " type="text"  placeholder="jusqu'au" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select class="form-control">
                                            <option value="0" disabled="" selected="">Type de disponibilité</option>
                                            <option title="Disponible" classname="event-available" color="#d4f2e6" value="5">Disponible</option>
                                            <option title="Flexible" classname="event-ask-me" color="#CDE5f9" value="3">Flexible me contacter</option>
                                            <option title="Indisponible" classname="external-events event-unavailable" color="#E7E7E7" value="1">Indisponible</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <input class="btn btn-default calendar-edition" type="button" id="add_date"  value="submit">
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!-- #datepicker-event -->
                            <div id="datepicker-event"></div>
                            <!-- popup period delete -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="deletePeriod" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                            </button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Etes-vous sûr?</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <p>Etes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette période ?</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-basic" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="delete_period">Supprimer</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- calendar -->
                            <div id="calendar" class="" value="">
       </div>
                            <!-- default value -->
                            <div id="default-events">
                                <label class="">Disponibilité par défaut <span class="grey-color small italic text-default-value">Choisissez l'option qui décrit le mieux la disponibilité de votre maison durant l'année</span></label>

                                <label class="radio default-available active">
                                    <input type="radio" color="#d4f2e6" name="default-date" id="default-date-4" value="4">
                                    <span class="color-available small">Disponible</span>
                                    Ma maison est  généralement disponible 
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio default-ask-me">
                                    <input type="radio" color="#CDE5f9" name="default-date" id="default-date-2" value="2" >
                                    <span class="color-ask-me small">Demandez moi</span>
                                    Mes dates sont flexibles
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio default-unavailable">
                                    <input type="radio" color="#E7E7E7" name="default-date" id="default-date-0" value="0">
                                    <span class="color-unavailable small">Indisponible</span>
                                    Ma maison est habituellement indisponible
                                </label>
                                <label class="default-guestwanted">
                                    <span class="color-wanted small">test</span>
                                    Je recherche activement des Invités <br>
                                    <small><em>(période non disponible par défaut)</em></small>
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <div id="return-message"></div>

                        </div>
```